# What does it mean to pay USD FRA-OIS?

Tags: libor, rates, ois

Would just like to check my understanding.

If I were to pay USD FRA-OIS, does it mean I'm paying the OIS leg and receiving fixed? And the fixed is because the 3mL is fixed at the start of the period/tenor of the contract?

So this implies that if the LIBOR-OIS spread widens, the trade would be in the money?

Thanks!

Comment: perhaps [this](https://ftalphaville.ft.com/2012/05/15/1001061/do-not-trust-the-fra-ois-spread/) article is of interest?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the answer in another forum (which fits my initial intuition). So just to share:

> FRA-OIS is traded via swap. So if you think the spread would widen you
>   pay on the swap. So you would pay OIS + Spread and receive Libor.

https://www.wallstreetoasis.com/forums/tech-questions-on-eurodollar-and-fed-funds-futures-hedging